# change default option in wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: functions, pluggable

I'm using  **wp_dropdown_categories()**  to output a dropdown.

In default view (without having clicked it) it shows the name of the *first category* in the list. I'd like it to say *"Categories"*. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the show_option_all argument:

```
<?php $args = array(
'show_option_all'    => 'Categories'
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>
```

[Function Reference/wp dropdown categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)